# PHP $_COOKIE Problems

Tags: php, cookies

Hello I have a quick question about my php setcookie for my site.  I recently added a remember me functionality and it will set the cookie and I have it set for 30 days.  If I go into view my cookies I can clearly see it is set.

However on the sign in page it will not echo the cookie.  It gives me this:

> Notice: Undefined index: remember_me in signin.php on line 11

I can clearly see the cookie is set in Mozilla Firefox when I go view my cookies for localhost, but `if(isset($_COOKIE['remember_me'])){echo $_COOKIE['remember_me'];}` but it won't echo my cookie.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Yes I called a session_start() at the very beginning of the code.  The sign in uses a session not a cookie for them to stay signed in and that way if they close the browser it essentially logs them off.

php:

```
$_SESSION['privileges'] = $userType;
$_SESSION['name'] = $userFName;
$_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;
$expire = time()+3600*24*30;
setcookie("remember_me", $u, $expire); //Set Username Cookie
```

the remember me is just for the sign in page to show their username

Comment: How did you set the cookie? Did you call session_start()? We need to know these things!

Comment: `$_COOKIE`, not `$_COOKE`.

Comment: change `echo $_COOKE['remember_me']` to `echo $_COOKIE['remember_me']`

Comment: Typo questions are not sufficiently general to help other people in the future.

Comment: I remember a problem with iis.  Any chance you are on Windows

Comment: The typo is just from me kind of rushing to type it all on here and not checking spelling     My actual code has no typos in my actual code

Comment: Kinjal Dixit   I am on windows but am using xampp

Comment: And what is `$u`?  Where is it being set?  We need example code that actually and semi-reliably *demonstrates the problem*.  Otherwise, we'll be guessing crap all day.

Comment: @cHao In what scenario would it matter what `$u` is? The second parameter of `setcookie` is some arbitrary value.

Comment: @zamnuts: In the scenario that *that's what's being set as the cookie value*.  Which, y'know, is the current case.  Whether it's what's *causing* the issue is not my main point; the point is that the code in the question is not nearly enough to actually make the problem show itself.   There's way too much info missing to even hazard a guess at the cause.  Particularly considering that at no point in any of this code is `$_COOKIE['remember_me']` even accessed  without ensuring it exists, which means the error message should never appear if what's here is as described.

Comment: The only common error i can imagine going on at this point is that the OP is attempting to mess with `$_COOKIE['remember_me']` after setting it in the current request, before the browser has received it and posted it back.  (`setcookie` doesn't modify `$_COOKIE`, which only contains the cookies actually sent by the browser unless you modify it by hand.  And that's a bad idea in itself.)  But that's wild speculation, because there's no code here that can demonstrate that it is or isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

check cookie array in the page first.

```
<?php
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

Check all values in the array. If you found remember_me then you can use. Otherwise you are not properly set the cookie.